# SQL query, Select available pitches by given date range

Tags: sql

I have been tasked to create a web enabled database where customers can book campsite pitches.

I am currently working on a SQL query to check what pitches are available during a certain date.

I have a 'Pitch' table which contains `pitch` and `type_id` columns, and a 'booking' table which contain pitch `StartDate` and `EndDate` columns. 
I currently have this:

```
SELECT Pitch 
FROM Pitch AS p
WHERE
    Pitch NOT IN (
        SELECT Pitch 
        From Booking As b
        WHERE b.Pitch IS NOT NULL 
          AND b.Pitch = p.pitch 
          AND (StartDate >= 15/06/2015 AND EndDate  <= 20/06/2015)  
        );
```

Comment: All I see here is a statement.  What is your question?

Comment: I would like the query to return only the pitches that are available during the two dates.

Comment: `15/06/2015` is not a valid syntax for a date literal in SQL (it's actually a number: 15 divided by 6 divided by 2015) - which DBMS accepts this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should take out the "`AS`" keyword when referring to a table.  That is usually only used for columns. Then, don't try to join in your sub-query. It might look something like this:

```
SELECT PITCH 
FROM PITCH 
WHERE PITCH NOT IN (
    SELECT PITCH FROM BOOKING
    WHERE WHERE STARTDATE >= 15/06/2015 --verify syntax of date
      AND ENDDATE <= 20/06/2015 );
```

Although I wouldn't recommend naming a column the same as a table.

Comment: Brill, this works great, i have changed the name of the collums in both the pitch and booking table, also had to remove one of the wheres from you solution,

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't realized I double typed WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `JOIN` like this
(to return only the pitches that are available during the two dates):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.pitch
FROM
    Pitch p
    JOIN
    Booking b ON p.pitch = b.pitch
WHERE
    b.StartDate >= '2015-06-15' 
AND b.EndDate <= '2015-06-20'
```

or using `EXISTS` like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.pitch
FROM
    Pitch p
WHERE
    EXISTS(    -- or add a `NOT` at first to return only the pitches that are not available during the two dates.
        SELECT 1
        FROM Booking b
        WHERE
            p.pitch = b.pitch
        AND b.StartDate >= '2015-06-15'
        AND b.EndDate <= '2015-06-20'
```